# When does autoboxing take place exactly?

Tags: java, autoboxing

Consider the following toy method:

```
public Float testReturnFloat() {
    return 2f;
}
```

And the following client code:

```
float resultOne = testReturnFloat();
Float resultTwo = testReturnFloat();
```

Do now both calls involve autoboxing, or only the latter, even though `Float testReturnFloat()` has been used as method signature?

*Small note: This question is only for theoretical analysis, I encountered it as I almost put this into production code due to a typo.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`testReturnFloat()` itself involves autoboxing because the primitive float `2f` is implicitly converted to a `Float` before it's returned. Now when you write

```
float resultOne = testReturnFloat();
```

the result is again *unboxed* to produce a primitive `float` which is then assigned to `resultOne`.

When you write

```
Float resultTwo = testReturnFloat();
```

nothing special happens. The `Float` returned by `testReturnFloat()` is assigned to `resultTwo`.

---

Really the best way to understand this is to look at the bytecode. Here's the bytecode for `testReturnFloat()`:

```
  public java.lang.Float testReturnFloat();
    Code:
       0: fconst_2      
       1: invokestatic  #57                 // Method java/lang/Float.valueOf:(F)Ljava/lang/Float;
       4: areturn
```

As you can see, `Float.valueOf()` is invoked on `2f` (`fconst_2`). This is the autoboxing I was talking about.

Now for your client code:

```
float resultOne = testReturnFloat();
```

becomes

```
   0: invokestatic  #16                 // Method testReturnFloat:()Ljava/lang/Float;
   3: invokevirtual #20                 // Method java/lang/Float.floatValue:()F
   6: fstore_1
```

Notice that unboxing occurs via `Float#floatValue()`.

Finally,

```
Float resultTwo = testReturnFloat();
```

becomes

```
   7: invokestatic  #16                 // Method testReturnFloat:()Ljava/lang/Float;
  10: astore_2
```

As I said, nothing special; the return value of `testReturnFloat()` is just stored in `resultTwo`.